# Python 3: Termination of threads in multiprocessing ThreadPool not working

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS and Python 3.5.2.
I have a `ThreadPool` from `multiprocessing` doing some work.
Now I want to terminate this pool while doing its work.

Using `ThreadPool.terminate()` does not work as expected.
When running the following example, the worker never stops doing its work and the program never runs past the `ThreadPool.join()` call.

```
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def task():
    try:
        while True:
            print("Working")
            time.sleep(1)
    except: # Unsuccessful attempt. :(
        print("Working, stopping now")

thread_pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)

thread_pool.apply_async(task)
time.sleep(1) # Make sure the task is actually started.

print("Terminating")
thread_pool.terminate()
print("Termination: Initiated")
thread_pool.join() # Does not return.
print("Termination: Done")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specifically requested a `ThreadPool` rather than a `Pool`.  This means that instead of creating a new process, the `multiprocessing` code will create a local thread (in your own process).

A `ThreadPool` instance cannot be terminated abruptly as there is no defined mechanism for that (vs a process, where the system can call `os.kill`).  In your code, the `.terminate` directive winds up being ignored.  In fact, it sets a flag that the pool instance would check when the task returns, but your task never returns.  We can see this with a revised version:

```
import argparse
import sys
import time

from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool

def task(arg):
    for i in range(3):
        print("Working on", arg, "with i =", i)
        time.sleep(1)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--delay', default=1, type=float)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    thread_pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)

    thread_pool.apply_async(task, (0,))
    thread_pool.apply_async(task, (1,))
    time.sleep(args.delay)

    print("Terminating")
    thread_pool.terminate()
    print("Termination: Initiated")
    thread_pool.join() # Does not return.
    print("Termination: Done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        sys.exit(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit('\nInterrupted')
```

which does this when run with no arguments:

```
$ python3 tp.py
Working on 0 with i = 0
Working on 0 with i = 1
Terminating
Termination: Initiated
Working on 0 with i = 2
Termination: Done
```

and this when run with `--delay 5`:

```
$ python3 tp.py --delay 5
Working on 0 with i = 0
Working on 0 with i = 1
Working on 0 with i = 2
Working on 1 with i = 0
Working on 1 with i = 1
Terminating
Working on 1 with i = 2
Termination: Initiated
Termination: Done
```

Alternatively, if you just use a `Pool` instead of a `ThreadPool`, you will get a real process and can use `.terminate` on it at any time (modulo the usual caveats about screwing up communications queues).

Comment: Thanks. I did know about the actual multiprocessing implementation which uses processes instead of threads, but I am required to use threads for my application. However, I didn't know that the implementation of `ThreadPool.terminate()` is actually that way. Is there any alternative to the `ThreadPool` which I could use without having to implement the termination communication functionality myself (and probably for every single task)? Having to do something like catching an exception in tasks is still fine of course.

Comment: If you go lower level than Python offers, you can send a signal to a specific thread. The mechanism is (obviously) machine dependent. There were various bugs in some systems' (FreeBSD for sure) thread signal handling, too, that may have workarounds in your Python, that could interfere further, so you'd have to experiment to make sure it works on your system. The portable way to do this would be to set a shared "time to stop!" variable and check it periodically in your task.